# Spring Boot: How to override properties with dash "-" on Linux ENV .profile?

Tags: linux, spring, spring-boot

I want to override ANY property in application.properties with an ENV setting.  In my application, I define properties using "prefix" with DOTs "." and suffix with "dash" (e.g., "-").

For example:

`application.server.jgroups-port= some port #`

Now, I want to override this property from the OS ENV settings.

On Windows, when I set this ENV property, this is my results:

First (FAILS),

```
Windows ENV >> APPLICATION_SERVER_JGROUPS_PORT = 5445

environment.getProperty("application.server.jgroups-port") returns NULL
```

Second (FAILS),

```
Windows ENV >> APPLICATION_SERVER_JGROUPSPORT = 5445

environment.getProperty("application.server.jgroups-port") returns NULL
```

Third (THIS WORKS!),

```
Windows ENV >> APPLICATION_SERVER_JGROUPS-PORT = 5445

environment.getProperty("application.server.jgroups-port") returns 5445
```

*Notice, the "dash" (e.g., "-") on the last one.*

YAY!  I have effectively set the property from the Windows ENV using a "dash".  Spring Boot maps this ENV perfectly to the application property.

On Linux, however, it does not accept a "dash" (e.g., "-") in its ENV, so my .profile blows up when I use the same approach that I used on Windows >> APPLICATION_SERVER_JGROUPS-PORT = 5445.  What do I need to do to make Linux ENV settings set my "application.server.jgroups-port" property?

EDIT:
It looks like the org.springframework.core.env.SystemEnvironmentPropertySource is where I'd need to do some work to support a dashed property name in Java as a Linux ENV.  For instance, a call to `getProperty("somePrefix.foo-suffix")`  = APPLICATION_SERVER_JGROUPS_PORT in the SystemEnvironmentPropertySource just like it had a period -  `getProperty("somePrefix.foo.suffix")`

Comment: It looks like the org.springframework.core.env.SystemEnvironmentPropertySource is where I'd need to do some work... Like somehow, supporting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I had to do to resolve the problem.

1. I subclassed, SystemEnvironmentPropertySource.java.
2. I overrode getProperty(name) and copied the parent's 'resolvePropertyName()' code to make my fix.  It is private, so I couldn't just override 'resolvePropertyName()', which would've been easier.
3. See resolvePropertyName() code snippet below.
4. I created an ApplicationListener and registered it in my Spring Boot app to add this custom PropertySource to the standard list of MutablePropertySources.

This is the guts of the change.  I think Spring should just add this capability in a future release.

```
    private String resolvePropertyName(String name) {
        Assert.notNull(name, "Property name must not be null");
        if (containsKey(name)) {
            return name;
        }

        String usName = name.replace('.', '_');
        if (!name.equals(usName) && containsKey(usName)) {
            return usName;
        }

        String ucName = name.toUpperCase();
        if (!name.equals(ucName)) {
            if (containsKey(ucName)) {
                return ucName;
            }
            else {
                String usUcName = ucName.replace('.', '_');
                if (!ucName.equals(usUcName) && containsKey(usUcName)) {
                    return usUcName;
                }

                // Jan. 27, 2015 - Jason
                // Added this code to allow replacing a property with dashes to underscores
                String usUcDashName = usUcName.replace("-", "_");
                if (containsKey(usUcDashName)) {
                    return usUcDashName;
                }
                // end modification to support dashes
            }
        }

        return name;
    }
```

And the JUnit to showcase what I needed to have happen.  The final assertion is what I originally opened this about.

```
@RunWith(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TestDashPropertySource extends TestCase{

    @Test
    public void testConvertBashToDash() throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> mockBashENV = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        mockBashENV.put("APP_PREFIX_FOO", "foo");
        mockBashENV.put("APP_PREFIX_BAR", "bar");
        mockBashENV.put("APP_PREFIX_FOO_BAR", "foobar");

        SystemEnvironmentDashResolvingPropertySource ps = new SystemEnvironmentDashResolvingPropertySource("my-dash-handler",mockBashENV);

        Object foo = ps.getProperty("app.prefix.foo");
        assertEquals("Did not find correct value", "foo", foo);

        Object bar = ps.getProperty("app.prefix.bar");
        assertEquals("Did not find correct value", "bar", bar);

        Object foobar1 = ps.getProperty("app.prefix.foo.bar");
        assertEquals("Did not find correct value", "foobar", foobar1);

        Object foobar2_W_Dashes = ps.getProperty("app.prefix.foo-bar");
        assertEquals("Did not find correct value", "foobar", foobar2_W_Dashes);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also provide an environment variable named `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON` with valid JSON in it. This will allow you to override keys with special characters. For example :

`export SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON='{"application.server.jgroups-port": 8080}'`

This way, you can also override arrays defined in yaml like this :

```
foo.bar:
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
```

with:

`export SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON='{"foo.bar": ["4","5","6"]}'`

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config

Comment: SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON is a fairly recent addition. You might have to update your Spring Boot Parent to get it to work.

Comment: True, it's part of the 1.3.x release.

Answer (score 3):

Your second attempt should work. According to the [Spring Boot Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.environment-variables):

> To convert a property name in the canonical-form to an environment
> variable name you can follow these rules:
>
> - Replace dots (.) with underscores (_).
> - Remove any dashes (-).
> - Convert to uppercase.

I just tested a very similar usecase and it worked well for me

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible directly,  but you can use `env` program. See this response https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23714

Comment: Hi - sorry, let me be more specific.  I'm not looking for a way to allow dashes in Linux ENV vars.  Instead, I am looking for a solution via Spring that will convert valid Linux ENV variables into Spring property overrides - even when the Spring property has a dash "-" in it.